# Reactjs gmail integration vs oauth GCP

Tags: reactjs, gmail

Can anyone provide some guidance on accessing gmail apis (get emails, create emails). I setup oauth on GCP and received an access token via react-google-login. I juust dont know which endpoints to use it for. the google documentation is a little sparse. links to documentation is much appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. i need to pass in the scope to the react-google-login package. afterwards i get a tokenObj which contains the access token which i can add as a Bearer to call the google endpoints here

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/get

^^ apis

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#gmail

^^ scopes